# How to store values into array from Database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, database

I am new to the laravel ,i write one database query which will fetch values from the database and stored into the database it's storing in the form of object but i need to store into the form of array, please help me to achieve this thing.

```
if(in_array('super-user',$types)){
   //my logic
}
```

**My expectation is**

$types=['admin','super-user'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case you are not looking to make any query return an array instead of objects you are looking to "pluck" a particular columns values:

```
$types = DB::table('status')->pluck('name')->all();
```

`pluck` gets the list of column values and the `all` method call returns the underlying array from the Collection instance returned from `pluck`.

You could also continue to use the Collection to do what you need instead of using an array:

```
$types = DB::table('status')->pluck('name');

if ($types->contains('super-user')) {
    ...
}
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Queries - Retrieving a List of Column Values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values) `pluck`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods -](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-all) `all`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods -](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains) `contains`